# Squared spin operators in second quantization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, operators, quantum-spin, second-quantization

Spin operator in second quantization can be written as:
\begin{equation}
\hat{\vec{S}}_{i} = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{\sigma \sigma'} \hat{c}^{\dagger}_{i\sigma} \hat{\vec{\sigma}}_{\sigma \sigma'} \hat{c}_{i\sigma'}
\end{equation}
where i - lattice multiindex, $\vec{\sigma}$ - Pauli matrices, $\hat{c}$ and $\hat{c}^{\dagger}$ - annihilation and creation fermion operators

I want to write $\left(\hat{S}^{x}_{i}\right)^{2}$, $\left(\hat{S}^{y}_{i}\right)^{2}$, $\left(\hat{S}^{z}_{i}\right)^{2}$, $\left(\hat{\vec{S}}_{i}\right)^{2}$.

For example,
$\hat{S}^{x}_{i} = \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{\sigma\neq\sigma'} \hat{c}^{\dagger}_{i\sigma}\hat{c}_{i\sigma'}$

Then it should be correct that

\begin{equation}
\left(\hat{S}^{x}_{i}\right)^{2} = \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{\sigma\neq\sigma', \delta\neq\delta'} \hat{c}^{\dagger}_{i\sigma}\hat{c}_{i\sigma'}\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{i\delta}\hat{c}_{i\delta'}
\end{equation}
The problem is, I struggle to simplify this expression. All I need to use is anticommutation relations, but every attempt leads to similar or even more complicated expressions. I failed to google answers. Is it even possible to combine somehow $\hat{c}$ and $\hat{c}^{\dagger}$ operators to get rid of some indexes or maybe transform this into function with operators $\hat{S}^{x}_{i}$, $\hat{S}^{y}_{i}$ , $\hat{S}^{z}_{i}$ ? If someone can give me a hint, I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: [Jordan-Schwinger map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_map#Fermions).

Comment: You might suppress the location index i, as different locations commute. Your Fock space then is 4 dimensional. Write the 4x4 matrix representing your operator.

Comment: *"The problem is, I struggle to simplify this expression."* Not sure if you consider this *more* simplified or *less* simplified, but you can also demand that $\sigma\neq\delta$ and that $\sigma'\neq\delta'$ in the last expression you wrote, since you can't create two electrons in the same state or destroy two in the same state...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> \begin{equation}
> \left(\hat{S}^{x}_{i}\right)^{2} = \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{\sigma\neq\sigma', \delta\neq\delta'} \hat{c}^{\dagger}_{i\sigma}\hat{c}_{i\sigma'}\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{i\delta}\hat{c}_{i\delta'}
> \end{equation}
> The problem is, I struggle to simplify this expression.

Write it out explicitly like:
$$
\left(\hat{S_i}^{x}\right)^{2} 
= \frac{1}{4} \left(\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{i\uparrow} \hat{c}_{i\downarrow} + \hat{c}^{\dagger}_{i\downarrow}  \hat{c}_{i\uparrow}\right)^2
= \frac{1}{4} \left(
\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{i\uparrow} \hat{c}_{i\uparrow}
+\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{i\downarrow} \hat{c}_{i\downarrow}-2\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{i\downarrow} \hat{c}_{i\downarrow}\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{i\uparrow} \hat{c}_{i\uparrow}\right)
=\frac{1}{4}\left(n_{i\uparrow} - n_{i\downarrow}\right)^2\;,
$$
where
$$
n_{i\uparrow}=n_{i\uparrow}^2=c^\dagger_{i\uparrow}c_{i\uparrow}
$$
and
$$
n_{i\downarrow}=n_{i\downarrow}^2=c^\dagger_{i\downarrow}c_{i\downarrow}\;.
$$

And the same expression results for $z$, much more easily:
$$
\left(\hat{S_i}^{z}\right)^{2} 
= \frac{1}{4} \left(\hat{c}^{\dagger}_{i\uparrow} \hat{c}_{i\uparrow} - \hat{c}^{\dagger}_{i\downarrow}  \hat{c}_{i\downarrow}\right)^2
=\frac{1}{4}\left(n_{i\uparrow} - n_{i\downarrow}\right)^2\;.
$$

And, I'll leave it to you to check that the $y$ expression gives the same result...

Thus:
$$
\left(\vec{S_i}\right)^{2}=\frac{3}{4}\left(n_{i\uparrow} - n_{i\downarrow}\right)^2
$$

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what you are really seeking, so I'd point out something specific for a given *i*, which I hitherto suppress, retaining just the two Pauli indices,
$$\hat{S}^{x} = \frac{1}{2} (\hat{c}^{\dagger}_1 \hat{c}_2 + \hat{c}^{\dagger}_2  \hat{c}_1)\qquad \implies \\
\left(\hat{S}^{x}\right)^{2} = \frac{1}{4} (\hat{c}^{\dagger}_1 \hat{c}_2 + \hat{c}^{\dagger}_2  \hat{c}_1)^2=   \frac{1}{4} ( \hat{c}^{\dagger}_1 \hat{c}_1+\hat{c}^{\dagger}_2 \hat{c}_2-2\hat{c}^{\dagger}_2 \hat{c}_2\hat{c}^{\dagger}_1 \hat{c}_1).
$$

Your Fock space is 4-dimensional, with two bosons intercalating two fermions,
$$
|0\rangle, \qquad \hat{c}^{\dagger}_1|0\rangle,  \qquad \hat{c}^{\dagger}_2|0\rangle, \qquad \hat{c}^{\dagger}_1\hat{c}^{\dagger}_2|0\rangle.$$

It is then clear the eigenvalue of the two boson states, the first and the fourth, under $(S^x)^2$ are 0, so these are projected out; while the eigenvalues on the two fermions, the middle two states, are both 1/4, so four times your operator projects out the boson states. Can you see it is idempotent?